# Rails 3.1 Filter 'Created_At' field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my Rails 3.1, ruby 1.9.2 application, I've an Object 'Post' that has several fields such as id,created_at,updated_at,name,description.... In my view I want show post.created_at field filtered by date: I explain better:
In my view I'd want something such as:

but html must render something such as:  2011-30-06 and not 2011-30-06 11:04 am

in other words I want display only date and not hour, how can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use *strftime* to format correctly the date (here's the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime))
It should look like this `<%= post.created_at.strftime("%Y-%M-%d) %>`

Comment: there is a shortcut for `%Y-%M-%d` -> `%F`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to create method **display_date** in application_helper.rb, don't forget about DRY!

```
 def display_date(input_date)
    input_date.strftime("%Y-%M-%d")
 end
```